# In what sense do we understand the Laplacian $\Delta u$ of $u$ if $u$ is only a member of the Sobolev space $W^{2,p}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $U$ be an open bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I'm trying to make sense of the equation
$$\langle\Delta u,\psi\rangle=\langle u,\Delta\psi\rangle,\tag{$*$}$$
where $u\in W^{2,p}(U)$ and $\psi\in C_c^\infty(U)$, and I was told that the angle brackets represent the pairing between distributions and test functions.

If I take the exposition literally, $\Delta u$ would be a distribution, but what is it really? Up to now, I haven't found any relevant definitions in my books on distributions. What I've got so far is that $u$ can be seen as a distribution defined by
$$\psi\in C_c^\infty(U)\mapsto\int_U u\psi.$$
That way, $\langle u,\Delta\psi\rangle$ would be understood as
$$\int_U u\Delta\psi.$$
As for $\Delta u$ in $(*)$, I'm not sure if it is defined by differentiating distributions, which is defined to be the operation $D^\alpha$ yielding another distribution
$$D^\alpha u:\psi\in C_c^\infty(U)\mapsto(-1)^{|\alpha|}u(D^\alpha\psi),\tag{$**$}$$
where $\alpha$ is a multi-index. That's because I saw from an online source that
$$(\Delta u)(\psi)=\int_U u\Delta\psi.\tag{$***$}$$
Is the Laplacian in $(***)$ equivalent to that defined via $(**)$? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you read is correct, distributions are (bounded) linear forms acting on $C^\infty_c$ functions (called test functions). If $f$ is a distribution, one often denotes by
$$
\langle f,\varphi\rangle = f(\varphi)
$$
its action on a rest function varphi. In the case of a classical locally integrable function (or a measure), then one identifies it with the distribution acting as
$$
\langle f,\varphi\rangle = \int f\,\varphi.
$$
But this is not always possible. In your case, for any distribution $u$,
$$
f_u : \varphi \mapsto \langle u,\Delta\varphi\rangle
$$
is indeed a linear form on $C^\infty_c$, hence defines a distribution. Now people chose to call it $\Delta u$, so that it extends the usual definition of the Laplacian, and with the notation above, one obtains your first formula
$$
\langle f_u,\varphi\rangle = \langle \Delta u,\varphi\rangle = \langle u,\Delta\varphi\rangle.
$$
Hence, here, the two first expressions are just notations to write the last one. Since your $u$ is a locally integrable function, then the last expression is indeed an integral so $(***)$ is indeed equivalent to $(*)$.

Indeed one can also define derivatives of distributions by $\langle \nabla f,\varphi\rangle = -\langle f ,\nabla\varphi\rangle$. In particular, since $\Delta\varphi = \nabla \cdot \nabla\varphi$, it follows from the definitions that
$$
\langle \Delta u,\varphi\rangle = \langle\nabla \cdot \nabla u,\varphi\rangle
$$
and so $(***)$ is equivalent to $(**)$.

Comment: Is the symbol $u$ in your answer initially a function in $W^{2,p}$ but later identified with a distribution induced by integration? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, exactly, $u$ is locally integrable and so automatically identified with a distribution by my second formula. In the same way that natural numbers are identified with real numbers ;)

Comment: Could you expand a little bit on what happens to $\nabla\cdot\nabla$ when you argue that two definitions are equivalent? Thank you.

Comment: By definition of $\nabla$, linearity of the evaluation map and the definition of the derivative of a distribution used twice
$$
\langle \nabla\cdot\nabla u,\varphi\rangle = \sum_j \langle \partial_j^2u,\varphi\rangle = -\sum_j \langle \partial_ju,\partial_j\varphi\rangle  = \sum_j \langle u,\partial_j^2\varphi\rangle
$$
Since $u$ is a linear form and by the classical definition of the Laplacian on smooth functions
$$
\sum_j \langle u,\partial_j^2\varphi\rangle = \langle u,\sum_j\partial_j^2\varphi\rangle = \langle u,\Delta\varphi\rangle
$$

Comment: Hence, by definition of the Laplacian of $u$, one concludes that for any test function $\varphi$
$$
\langle \Delta u,\varphi\rangle = \langle \nabla\cdot\nabla u,\varphi\rangle
$$
which can also be written
$$
\Delta u = \nabla\cdot\nabla u \ \text{ in the sense of distributions.}
$$

Comment: I'd like to ask an irrelevant question if you don't mind. Suppose $\Delta u_i\to 0$ in $L^p$, where $\Delta u_i$'s are the Laplacians defined via **weak derivatives**. Now, can we conclude that $$\lim_{i\to\infty}\langle\Delta u_i,\varphi\rangle=0,$$ where $\Delta u_i$'s are the **distributional** Laplacians? Thank you.

Comment: I asked it in another post. Maybe you can visit some other time. Thank you. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4517170/when-do-we-have-lim-i-to-infty-langle-delta-u-i-phi-rangle-0-if-the-laplac